# output order is changed when redirecting from python script to output file

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am running a python script, in bash on a mac, which runs a series of tests in a for loop. It reads a file for the test names, and for each name it runs a cmd, which produces some output on stderr and stdout. I am redirecting the output of the script into a file like this:

```
python3 script.py names.txt > out.txt 2>&1
(alternatively) python3 script.py names.txt &> out.txt
```

What I am getting in out.txt is something like this:

```
outputs for name1
outputs for name2
============================
running name1
============================
running name2
============================
```

ie, the outputs of the cmd executable are coming faster than the outputs from the script.

Do I need to flush the output, everytime I print a line from the script? What is the command for that?

The python script is shown below:

```
    f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    namelist = f.readlines()
    print('============================')
    for name in namelist:
          name = name.rstrip(' ')
          name = name.rstrip(' \n\t')
          print('running {}'.format(name))
          os.system('some_cmd {}'.format(name))
          print('============================')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could try and flush the buffer after each print:

```py
print(name, flush=True)
```

but I would recommend using [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `os.system`.
This is the recommended way to call a bash script in python:

```py
output = subprocess.check_output([some_cmd, name])
print(output)
```

This way all the outputs will be stored in the same buffer, which will keep the correct order in `out.txt`.

Also, now you could just open `out.txt` and write the output directly to the file.